# Force 'Replace Into' to use a certain index

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL (5.0) table with 3 rows which are considered a combined Unique Index:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`table_a` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field1` varchar(5) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `field2` varchar(5) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `field3` varchar(5) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  INDEX `IdxUnqiue` (`field1`(5),`field2`(5),`field3`(5))
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

This table should be filled with a `REPLACE INTO` query:

```
REPLACE INTO
    table_a
(
    Field1,
    Field2,
    Field3
)
VALUES
(
    "Test1",
    "Test2",
    "Test3"
)
```

The behavior I'd like to see is that this query always overrides the previous inserted row, because `IdxUnique` is...ahm, triggered. But unfortunately, there's still the primary index which seems to kick in and always inserts a new row.

What I get:

```
Query was executed 3 times:

+---Id---+---Field1---+---Field2---+---Field3---+
| 1      | Test1      | Test2      | Test2      |
| 2      | Test1      | Test2      | Test2      |
| 3      | Test1      | Test2      | Test2      |
+--------+------------+------------+------------+
```

What I want:

```
Query was executed 3 times:

+---Id---+---Field1---+---Field2---+---Field3---+
| 3      | Test1      | Test2      | Test2      |
+--------+------------+------------+------------+
```

So, can I tell `REPLACE INTO` to use just a certain Index or to consider one 'more inportant' then another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `INDEX` keyword you are not creating a [unique index](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp), but a normal non-unique index. That is why you are being allowed to insert rows with non-distinct (field1, field2, field3).

Therefore all you need to do is to set your index as `UNIQUE` in your `CREATE TABLE` construct, as in the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_a` (
   `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `field1` varchar(5) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `field2` varchar(5) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `field3` varchar(5) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
   UNIQUE `IdxUnqiue` (`field1`(5),`field2`(5),`field3`(5))
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Insert the test data:

```
REPLACE INTO table_a (Field1, Field2, Field3) VALUES ("Test1", "Test2", "Test3");
REPLACE INTO table_a (Field1, Field2, Field3) VALUES ("Test1", "Test2", "Test3");
REPLACE INTO table_a (Field1, Field2, Field3) VALUES ("Test1", "Test2", "Test3");
```

Result:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a;

+----+--------+--------+--------+
| Id | field1 | field2 | field3 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
|  3 | Test1  | Test2  | Test3  |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Whoops...my mistake, I just forget to check the box. Ahm, but that's working...odd...that means I've a logical error somewhere in my 'real' table, screwing with my index. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Is there way to do this if you don't have a unique key. Like insert but update if you find a certain row with the same value on a particular column?